# TCP RST and 503 http error code

Tags: rest, tcp, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-503

My Client call RESTful api uri with httpwebrequest object.
but it sometimes returns 503 service is unavailable message.
So I captured tcp packet with wireshark and found out there TCP RST was happend at that time.

I want to capture TCP RST status ahead and give another http status code to it.
Is there any way to catch TCP RST status in HTTPwebrequest??
(ssl is applied to this restful request)...

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. TCP RST resets the connection, and HTTP 503 is delivered via the connection. You can't give any status at all *after* the RST. You can only get the 503 first and then the RST, not the other way around, so the 503 is what you ought to be investigating.

Comment: Exact flow is like this... after request... client cannot receive ACK from server, so client sent DUP ACK to server (TCP retransmission..) but cannot receive, too. so Finally client sent another ACK to server.. after that client got FIN ACK from server... then client sent RST ACK to server... those are wireshark packet sequence.... Maybe you're right. becuase i cannot sure what sequence did cause 503... please give your opinion

Comment: If 503 is unique signal in this situation, is ther any way to find out whether 503 is happend becuase of real server error or just network error... plz give your opinion

Comment: My opinion is worthless without the data, and only you can supply that. 503 is not a 'unique signal in this situation', if 'this situation' is the one that concerns resets. I've already said that. You are going to have to reproduce the 503 and post the data here: in your answer please, not as comments.